# Multiple JSON format to one Object

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, dozer

I have parser that parse multiple website and extract needed data and for each one produce `JSON` file. Each `JSON` file have different format but have same logic.
For example:

**site 1 JSON**

```
{ url:"site1.url.com",
  name: "site1Name",
  owner:"ownerName",
  category:"book,magazine",
  content:{
    book:[{ name:"book1",author:"author1"},
        {name:"book2",author:"author2",...],
    magazine:[...] 
  }
}
```

**site 2 JSON**

```
{ url:"site2.url.com",
  title: "site2Name",
  manager:"ownerName2",
  category:"software",
  content:{
    software:[{ name:"software1",author:"author1"},
        {name:"software2",author:"author2",...]
   }
}
```

**site 3 JSON**

```
{ link:"site3.url.com",
  label: "site3Name",
  admin:"ownerName3",
  category:"software",
  content:{
    software:[{ title:"Firefox",type:"browser"},
        {title:"InteliJ",type:"IDE",...]
   }
}
```

Now, I want to collect all data in my Java `Spring-MVC` application. then merge them to my models and persist them to database structure format. Note that my models and database structure is different than `JSON` parsed data.

**I try this solution:**
First create one `JSON` Object per site ( `JSON` file) and use Jackson to deserialize `JSON` to my object. and then use `DozerMapper` to map objects to my Models and persist them to database.

Is there better solution?

**Note:**

- the number of sites ( `JSON` files)  can greater than `100` with `100` different format. If i use this solution, I need `100` different Object per site and then `100` `XML` `DozerMapper`. Refactoring and developing this big workspace not easy and  that's not good!!!

Answer (score 0):

With Jackson's [`JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) constructor annotation and [`@JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) parameter annotations you can map the JSON fields right into your own model fields correctly, so you shouldn't need Dozer. So something like this:

```
public class MyModel {
  final String url;
  final String title;
  final String owner;

  protected MyModel(String url, String title, String owner) {
    this.url = url;
    this.title = title;
    this.owner = owner;
  }
}

public class Site2Model extends MyModel {
  @JsonCreator
  public Site2Model(
      @JsonProperty("url") String url,
      @JsonProperty("title") String title,
      @JsonProperty("manager") String owner) {
    super(url, title, owner);
  }
}
```

This assumes a JSON structure like in your site 2 example (url, title and manager), but maps those values to fields named `url`, `title` and `owner`. For site 1 you'd create another subclass of `MyModel` and would create different kinds of constructor mappings.

If you use the more advanced Jackson annotations like [`@JsonTypeInfo`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html) etc, and you make the "url" value your type-deciding property<sup>1)</sup>, you can even have the whole process work automatically in the sense that you just push different kinds of JSON documents to Jackson and it would be automatically able to know which subclass to use for the deserialization process. I won't go into details with this one, but [Baeldung has a good resource on Jackson annotations](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations).

<sup>1)</sup> **EDIT:** OK, I see you added "site 3" example, where there's no "url" value... But the first part of this answer still stands. And since you must know the site from where the JSON documents come from, maybe you could pre-process them and append a new key-value pair to each of them, like `"site": "Site1"` and use that as the Jackson subtype identifier instead?